# Fatal error: Call to a member function ola() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso utilizar bibliotecas no Codeigniter versão 2.1.4 e estou com problemas quanto à utilização dessas bibliotecas próprias. Depois de carregar a biblioteca (com `$this->load->library('Nomedabiblioteca');` no meu *controller*), tenho a linha de código:

```
$a = $this->Nomedabiblioteca->teste();
```

Para receber o retorno do método `teste()` da classe. Porém, nesta linha de código, o *controller* retorna o erro a seguir:

> "Call to a member function teste() on a non-object".

Como posso resolver essa situação? O que estou fazendo de errado?

O código da biblioteca é o seguinte (código para teste):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nomedabiblioteca{
    public function teste(){
        $a = 'algo';
        return $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu código é `$a = $this->Nomedabiblioteca->teste();` ou `"$a = $this->Nomedabiblioteca->teste();"`?

Comment: Utilize a função `var_dump` para verificar a propriedade `Nomedabiblioteca`: `var_dump($this->Nomedabiblioteca);`

Comment: o código é $a = $this->Nomedabiblioteca->teste();

Comment: O var_dump retorna null na propriedade. Undefined property

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar trocando o nome da classe de

```
$a = $this->Nomedabiblioteca->teste(); //Capitalizada
```

Para

```
$a = $this->nomedabiblioteca->teste();
```

Ao que tudo indica o codeigniter não funciona para as libraries da mesma forma que para controllers, models e views.